# How to put two inline input field correctly with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I do the following at `<div class="offset3 span6">` with `bootstrap-responsive.css`:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="passport1">Series and passport number</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="input-small inline" id="passport1" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
    <input type="text" class="input-medium inline" id="passport2" placeholder="" maxlength="6">
    <p class="help-block">Please input your passport details into two fields above</div>                    
  </div>
</div>
```

But text label is not aligned with input fields (it is lower). How to fix it?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/5S5CB/)

Comment: Do you have a test example somewhere?

Comment: @BarryChapman, just created it - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/5S5CB/

Comment: How do you want it to line up?

Comment: Top of the text should be at the same level where top of input is, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a top padding on your label of 5px;

Consider overriding this inline or creating a more specific css selector and try again.